# Handling form submissions without handling changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to front-end development so please forgive me if this is an ignorant question. I'm using ReactJS to build a simple SPA with several form components. In the official React docs and other tutorials I've read online, it seems like to be able to handle a form submission, I also have to handle form changes, i.e. update the component state with each keystroke, like so:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This seems wasteful to me since I'm only interested in the final form value that's been submitted. Is there a way to access the value of the submitted form in the submission event handler so that I can only update the state once and eliminate the need to handle any non-submission change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem wasteful, but that is exactly the React way of doing it:

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Any way of trying to get around this would be more hacky than efficient. This may help keep you from duplicating code while trying to track all your input values:

> When you need to handle multiple controlled input elements, you can add a name attribute to each element and let the handler function choose what to do based on the value of event.target.name.

This way you only need one 'handleChange' method.

Comment: Thanks! Writing one handleChange method is better than writing four, so I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

A controlled component is not really necessary in this case. Update the input component to:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required/>
```

Now handle only the onSubmit. The value can be retrieved at:

```
event.target.username.value
```

Add the attribute "required" to the input tag for automatic validation.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought React has one-way binding?

Comment: Yes it is one way by default. I meant to say controlled component. I do not see a need for it here. Read this for a longer explanation of react two way binding https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/tutorial-react-two-way-data-binding-2018-b935cb200964